# stream.count() resulting in NPE

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, java-stream

I am seeing some weird behaviour in Java stream API. Here's my code:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    final List<String> list = Arrays.asList( "string1", "string2" );
    final Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put( "string1", Arrays.asList( "1" ) );
    //map.put( "string2", Arrays.asList( "1" ) );
    Stream<String> stream = list.stream().map( map::get ).flatMap( List::stream );
    System.out.println( "Stream=" + stream );
    long count = stream.count();
    System.out.println( "Stream count=" + count );
}
```

The second last line (`long count = stream.count();`) is resulting in a NPE. The exception does not occur if I add another entry to map for key "string2" (commented code). Can somebody please point-out why it results in a NPE instead of just returning the count as 1?

The same behaviour is observed if I try to collect the stream's result in a list instead of calling `count()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will call `List#stream` on null in the `flatMap`, which results in a NullPointerException. You need to filter out null values before the flatMap:

```java
list.stream()
        .map(map::get)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .flatMap(List::stream)
```

Answer (score 1):

`.map( map::get )` when applied on the second element of your Stream ("string2") returns `null`. When `.flatMap( List::stream )` is applied on that `null` element, you get `NullPointerException`, since it tries to execute `stream()` method on a null reference.

You should filter out the `null` elements to avoid this:

```
Stream<String> stream = list.stream()
                            .map( map::get )
                            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                            .flatMap( List::stream );
```

Answer (score 1):

[Map.get()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get-java.lang.Object-) will return `null`, when there is no mapping for the key in the map, as stated in the docs.

> Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or null if this map contains no mapping for the key.

To fix, filter out null elements from the stream.

```
Stream<String> stream = list.stream()
    .map(map::get)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .flatMap(Collection::stream);
```

Or you can supply default value, using [Map.getOrDefault()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-).

> Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or defaultValue if this map contains no mapping for the key.

```
Stream<String> stream = list.stream()
     .map(str -> map.getOrDefault(str, Collections.emptyList()))
     .flatMap(Collection::stream);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do

`map.get("string2")` you will get `null`

when you do
`map.get("string2").stream()` you will get NPE

This is exactly what you are doing in your stream.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
.map( map::get )
```

you get list containing `"1"` by key `"string1"` from `map`, then `null` by key `"string2"`. This causes NPE